# Is there a workaround for typecasting a function pointer to an object pointer in C?

Tags: c, pointers, function-pointers, void-pointers

I have a function called 'bench' which accepts a function pointer that returns a void pointer (for generics).

`static inline unsigned long bench(void* (*funcPtr)(va_list), ...)`

But if I pass it a function that returns anything else, I get this error -

`passing argument 1 of 'bench' from incompatible pointer type`

So it outright refuses to type cast. But then if I manually type cast it to a void pointer when calling the bench function, I get this error -

`ISO C forbids passing argument 1 of 'bench' between function pointer and 'void *'`

A workaround I got to know is to use a wrapper function which returns a void pointer, but then I would have to either create a new wrapper function for every individual function I need to pass, which would be very inefficient, and the other way would be to create a wrapper function for every data type that I will use, which is not that inefficient, but it is. Is there a better workaround?

Comment: You need to make your functions conform to the interface.

Comment: The best way is to pass the correct type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

C has no generic pointer-to-function type, like `void *` is for objects. However, you can convert any pointer-to-function to any other pointer-to-function type. So, to pass the function `foo` to `bench`, you can convert it to the parameter type of `bench`:

```
bench((void *(*)(va_list)) foo);
```

While that will work to convert and pass the pointer, calling the function relies on it being called via its proper type (something matching its declaration according to the rules for function calls). If `foo` is not defined in a way compatible with the way that `bench` calls the function, you will need a wrapper function.

Comment: You mean something like this? 

`bench((void*) (*)(va_list) my_strlen1), str);` 

If so, then this does not work. I am getting multiple errors like va_list is not allowed, and expected an expression on the asterisk.

Comment: @Programmer_2147483647: I had a stray `)` in the code. It is fixed now.

Comment: This actually still does not work. I get this error - error: `cast between incompatible function types from 'long unsigned int (*)(const char *)' to 'void * (*)(char *)'`
This is how my statement looks like - `printf("my_strlen1 elapsed: %ld\n", bench((void *(*)(va_list)) my_strlen1, str));`

Comment: @Programmer_2147483647: That is an extra error message in your compiler, not one required by the C standard. Turn it off. Or write a wrapper for the function.